# Is it possible to customize errorhandler in mysql-python? (using peewee)

Tags: python, mysql-python, peewee

I am writing a mibbleware around `mysql-python`. The aim is to wrap all mysql errors to my own handler instead of throwing an exceptiong and break the logic.

My middleware is using `peewee` like this

```
def my_hander(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue):
    pass # my customized middleware logic here

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase('backend', host= .... )
db.get_conn().errorhandler = my_hander
```

However no matter what I try, `my_handler` will not be triggered and exceptions goes to peewee & mysql's as usual.

My question is is there any canonical way to make mysql-python throw exceptions to my own handler instead of going to `MySQLdb/connections.py: def defaulterrorhandler()` ?

Python 2.7, Ubuntu 12.04, other libs using latest.